# Postman mock returns always 200

Tags: rest, postman

I'm mocking an API endpoint using postman, I created under the same url {{baseURL}}/api/users three so called example: for 200, 300, 400 status code.

The difference between these examples is just a header key (id_user).
id_user: 121 for the 200 status code
id_user: blank for the 400
id_user: 0 for the 500

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gEPs.png)
[header-key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3a4X.png)

It seems that postman fail to differentiate beetween these call using just header key-values (query params and path variables excluded), it answer always with 200 OK.